# Heroku + Git public key

Tags: git, heroku, github-for-windows

```
$ heroku keys:add
Found existing public key: C:/Users/Andre/.ssh/github_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/Andre/.ssh/github_rsa.pub... done
Andre@ANDREH /c/Unisinos/Desenvolvimento de Software/unidemico (master)
$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any idea why Am I getting this errors? I do have a public key in github_rsa.pub file...
Also at https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/XXXApp/settings I set my public key

help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following to list your ssh keys currently in your key chain:

```
ssh-add -l
```

You should see something like this:

```
2048 3c:a8:e1:...:f7 /Users/.../.ssh/github_rsa (RSA)
```

If you don't, it means your key is not loaded. Do:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

Then it should work

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: $ heroku login

Enter your Heroku credentials.

Email: xxxx@gmail.com

Password (typing will be hidden):

Authentication successful.

Andre@ANDREH /c/Unisinos/Desenvolvimento de Software/unidemico(master)

$ ssh-add -l

Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: It depends on the software you are using type your commands... Putty ?

Comment: actually I'm using git bash command line... to start this context at  Andre@ANDREH /c/Unisinos/Desenvolvimento de Software/unidemico(master) $ I do type following command in Windows: git

Comment: C:\Unisinos\Desenvolvimento de Software\unidemico>git

C:\Unisinos\Desenvolvimento de Software\unidemico>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c
 ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.1.2-preview20130201)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
Andre@ANDREH /c/Unisinos/Desenvolvimento de Software/unidemico (master)
$

Comment: Ok maybe you'll find the solution here http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Comment: $ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:protected-garden-2441.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:protected-garden-2441.git (push)
Andre@ANDREH /c/Unisinos/Desenvolvimento de Software/unidemico (master)
$ heroku git:remote -a protected-garden-2441
 !    Git remote heroku already exists

Andre@ANDREH /c/Unisinos/Desenvolvimento de Software/unidemico (master)
$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre-Louis Gottfrois comments helped me, I didnt have an id_rsa.pub created properly, now its working fine!